# Get distinct pattern match results (substrings) from PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo-3.x

**What is the most efficient way to query a MongoDB collection for unique/distinct substrings in a given field?**

Example documents:

```json
{"_id": "1234.abc.test1", "some_key": "some_value"}
{"_id": "1234.abc.test2", "some_key": "some_value"}
{"_id": "0420.def.test3", "some_key": "some_value"}
```

The document IDs above follow an internal namespacing convention. I need to know what all of the distinct first elements of that namespacing are.

The desired output of the query on the above collection:

```
1234
0420
```

I am trying to avoid getting the entire dataset back only to do `row['_id'].split('.')[0]` on each row afterwards. Ideally, the query should return only the distinct list of those substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is actually the same as yours(i.e. splitting by `.` and get the first element), then `$group` them to get distinct records.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      first: {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          {
            "$split": [
              "$_id",
              "."
            ]
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$first"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BjiM40DAmC8) for your reference.

Here is the PyMongo implementation of the above query:

```py
pipeline = [
    {"$project": {"first": {"$arrayElemAt": [{"$split": ["$_id", "."]}, 0]}}},
    {"$group": {"_id": "$first"}}
]
result = self.collection.aggregate(pipeline=pipeline, allowDiskUse=False)
```

Comment: @muadDweeb Thanks for helping to supplement the PyMongo implmentation